# no module named 'ttk', but its in the folder

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to create a window with tkinter and ttk. When I run the script on my Windows 7 Pro PC I get the error stating there is no module named ttk, but when I look in my PC, I see the module. This exact script also works on my RPi with out a problem. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reinstall ttk, and if so, how?

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import * 
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)

        tk.Label(self, text = 'Hi').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Button 1', width = 10, fg = 'red', command = self.button).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.grid()

    def button(self):
        print('Yo')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain what is causing the problem in your program also I have made some changes to your posted code and explain a few things.

Comment: are you running python 2 or 3? The way you import ttk is different between those two versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

So I see several problems with your program.

Keep in mind tkinter and ttk come with python by default on windows versions. You should not have to reinstall tkinter. If there is a problem with your python then you should reinstall python instead.

The issue here is not the `ttk` import but `mainloop` you must call mainloop with `()` so do `mainloop()` instead.

If you only change `root.mainloop` to `root.mainloop()` your program will work in python 2.

However there are several things wrong with your program.

take a look at the following:

```
try:
    # Python 3.x
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk #this is how we import for Python 3.x
except:
    # Python 2.x
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk # this needs to be inside the except: not outside like you had it.
    # this is because if you were to move to python 3 with this it would not work and cause an error.

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    # I added in the *args and ** kwargs to show what a full class __init__ can accept.
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        # for your label and button you need to set it as a variable.
        self.my_label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'Hi').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.my_button = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Button 1', width = 10, fg = 'red', command = self.button).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    def button(self):
        print'Yo'
        # print('Yo') # python 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = MainWindow(root) # you should define your main window as something. This way you can interact with the object from outside.
    tk.mainloop() # this must be called in order to tkinter to work.
```

Update:

per you question in comments:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MintApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.py_frame_color = "orange" # this is an attribute
        self.root.config(bg = self.py_frame_color)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 

    MyApp = MintApp(root)

    print(MyApp.root.cget('bg'))

    tk.mainloop()
```

Console results:

```
orange
```

by giving a name to the class we are creating an object with we are able to interact with its attributes from outside of the class.

We can also change attributes of an object from outside of the class. If you were to add this line `MyApp.root.config(bg = "blue")` to the example you will see the window changes to blue.

Comment: Thank you very much. This cleared it up. I do have a follow up question. You talk about naming the main window to interact with the object from out side, what do you mean. As you can tell, I'm a total noob.

Comment: @CowardlyDoomsday: I will add the example to my answer so you can see the results but eventually we do this so we can interact with the objects attributes from outside of the class. This can let us do lots of fun stuff. See the update on my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 the methods to import ttk are as follows

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Or

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

To override the tkinter base widgets.

For Python 2

```
import ttk
```

Or

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

are the documented methods.

If neither of these work, it suggests something is wrong with the installation.

(If you are using Python 2.7, please start using Python 3, [Python 2 is almost end of life](https://pythonclock.org/)).

Comment: I should of clarified that I am using 2.7. I did try switching to python3 and used this, but my window did not generate. The error did go away though.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sounds like you have an installation problem. Reinstall python from scratch.